# Adjust scrolling of div behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was alerted to a behavior I am not sure how to prevent in a hidden div, which appears once a polygon is clicked in this fiddle --

http://jsfiddle.net/mkhines/pTgxa/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
}

.info {
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: white;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
    word-wrap: normal;
    max-width: 45%;
}

.info h4 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    color: #2b4eb6;
    font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The desired behavior is that I don't want the background map `(#map)` to `scroll` when the user is perusing the results `(#info)` of their `click` with the vertical scroll bar in the div.

Any thoughts on a `CSS` solution for this? It only seems to show itself in `Firefox.` Essentially, when scrolling down, the map also moves behind it.

Thank you!
Megan

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable scrolling when the popup is displayed

```
info.update(html);
map.dragging.disable();
map.touchZoom.disable();
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
```

I added a resetMapControls function that is triggered when clicking on the "Reset Selection" button. This will enable scrolling again on close.

```
function resetMapControls(){
    map.dragging.enable();
    map.touchZoom.enable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
    map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
}
```

Checkout the following : http://jsfiddle.net/pTgxa/16/

More details on disabling scrolling below
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/disable-zooming-panning/

Comment: Thank you so much Yannick, that is exactly the kind of solution we can use! I'm a newbie here so I can't vote you up yet. I'm sure others may find this useful too who have that capability. Thanks again!